# get month,date, year php time from sql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
1398305717 <- my sql database time code like this
```

mysql time row name is `time`

.php

```
$numMonth = date('m', $time);

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE date('m',`time`) = $numMonth DESC LIMIT 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
echo $id = $row['id'];
```

i want to get last id equals to month numer? so i tried to like this.. but not work. how to get it from php. so help me to this post how to get month number from sql.. thanks.

Edit :
i want like this.. but not work :(

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(`time`)) = '$numMonth' DESC LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: what you mean not working. post your error code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to convert the timestamp then extract the month. and you don't need to use php date functions to get the current month you can just use mysql's functions to do it

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`time`),'%Y') as year,DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`time`),'%m') as month FROM videos WHERE MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(`time`)) = MONTH(CURDATE()) ORDER BY ID  LIMIT 1");
```

working demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4e465/8

don't forget about year, if you expect multiple years of timestamps

Comment: you need to be more descriptive than that

Comment: have error from this code Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result

Comment: oh thanks friend :) thanks lot of if u can tell me how to get this value from sql? month name(ex: march), year,date(ex : 02)

Comment: DATE_FORMAT() http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: friend i cant find it.. plzz if u can give me a code get year like this 2014 only and date like this 05.. plzz your answer edit for this one.. thanks

Comment: added year and month.